# How to integrate hangfire into the DotnetNuke backend

Tags: dotnetnuke, hangfire

I have a long process method that needs to be handled by a background process. I am thinking of using a HangFire. It is a free and open-source framework that will allow you to easily perform background processing in .NET application. The catch is I am new to DNN and I don't know how to start. I am searching in Google on how to integrate it, but I can't find a reference for that. Anyone has an idea on how to integrate HangFire to DNN?

Comment: If a module using hangfire is not for sale in the [DNN store](http://store.dnnsoftware.com/), you're gonna have to build your own module.

Comment: @VDWWD, Do you an idea on how can I configure and build HangFire inside DNN? I know how to build HangFire in any .NET apps, but I have no experience yet  in DNN.

Comment: In a module you can do the same as other .net apps, and that includes using hangfire. But DNN has a build in scheduler also for which you can write a service.

Comment: The background process that I am going to make is not a scheduler, it is triggered by a button in client side, then the background process should start. The purpose of this is to separated the process that holds the long running method asynchronously, even If I navigate to other pages or exit the page it is still processing my request.

Comment: Then a module is your best bet. You could also create a standalone page that has nothing to do with DNN and put it in the portal. Then call that page with ajax and execute the hangfire. But that is an ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a .NET project and install Owin and Hangfire packages in the project.
In that project,
create an Owin startup class and put your Hangfire initialization code in the `Configuration` method like this:

```cs
using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(DnnHangfireIntegration.Startup))]

namespace DnnHangfireIntegration
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangfireConnection");
            app.UseHangfireServer();
            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/desktopmodules/hangfire");
        }
    }
}
```

You must configure the hangfire dashboard to use '/desktopmodules/hangfire' URL so it won't be intercepted by DNN.
Compile your project and copy your project DLL, Hangfire DLL's and Owin DLL's to your DNN bin-folder.

Lastly, you'll have to update the web.config to tell Hangfire how to find your startup class. You can do this by using this appsetting:

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>
```

Also don't forget to add the connectionstring, you could also just reuse the existing connectionstring.

For a more detailed walkthrough, check out my blog post: https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-add-hangfire-to-dnn